# What is the difference of Additonal Include Directories and Additional #using Directories?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, include-path, visual-studio-project

In Visual Studio (**Visual C++**)Project setting we able see these settings:

- Additional Include Directories (**/I[path]** compiler switch)
- Additional #using Directories (**/AI[path]** compiler switch)

---

I want to know when to use these settings appropriately and what the main differences between these settings and how they affect on *visual c++ linker and build time*?

[Please look at here -Visual Studio Property page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxxAK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#using` is for C++/CLI, not for standard C++.

> A directory to search to resolve file references passed to the `#using` Directive directive.

**assembly_A.cpp**

```
// compile with: /clr /LD  
public ref class A {};
```

**assembly_B.cpp**

```
// compile with: /clr /LD  
#using "assembly_A.dll"  
public ref class B {  
public:  
   void Test(A a) {}  
   void Test() {}  
};
```

The option `/AI[path]` would set a search path where assembly_A.dll is placed.

More official info: [VCCLCompilerTool.AdditionalUsingDirectories Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.additionalusingdirectories?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Comment: Thank you, that means #using mostly useful for C++/CLI rather than native C++ project settings?
Also sorry I cannot vote up your answer since I have no privileges yet.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, it is useless in the native C++ project settings.

Comment: That is not accurate, the #import directive relies on it as well.  And to locate WinRT meta files.  All pure native C++ projects.

Comment: @HansPassant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp does not specify `/AI`, only `/I` in *Search Order for filename*